# Black box appears at the bottom of website

Tags: html, css, web, box

I have a simple website.

When I test it offline by hosting it on localhost everything works fine.

However when I transfer the webpage to my hosting server and access it from the internet a black box appears at the bottom of the page as i scroll down. This does not happen when testing offline only online.

Stanger still if i rotate my screen to landscape and then back to portrait then the problem seems to go away , however if i reload the page it reappears.

Ps. I am accessing the website online using a mobile phone.

[This is what the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvkrO.png)

[This is what problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZKoU.png)

[This is how it looks after i rotate my screen to landscape and then portrait, this is the desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Htl.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tw+Cen+MT+Condensed');

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Tw Cen MT Condensed', sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: whitesmoke;
    position: fixed;
    height: 135px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}


.streamicon img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
}

.headerlogo img {
    width: 556px;
    height: 92px;
    left: 29%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .footer {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 44px;
    left: 93.2%;
    height: 22px;
    width: 65px;
}

.spinner {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 18px;
    background-color: black;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 18px;
    background-color: black;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 8px;
    top: 17px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -12px;
}


.footer {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left:4vw;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}


    .footer a {
        color: #0f98fe;
        font-size: 35px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .footer div{
        height:21px;
    }

    .footer img {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        padding-bottom: 32px;
        position: static;
    }

    .footer #end {
        margin-top: 400px;
        height: 590px;
        position: absolute;
        border-top: 0px solid;
        font-size:35px;
    }

    .footer #credit {
        display: inline;
        color: black;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .footer span {
        color: #0f98fe;
    }

    .footer #end div{
        height:21px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <title>Impressions</title>

    <link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <ul class="header">
            <li class="streamicon"> <a href="Index.html#stream-link"><img src="sys_media/radio_tower_black.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="headerlogo"> <a href="Index.html"><img src="sys_media/MenuBar_Logo.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
    <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
        <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </label>

    <div class="footer">

        <div id="end">
            <img src="../sys_media/main_logo.png" /><br />
            Copyright &copy;. 2021<br />
            <div></div>
            <a id="credit" href="www.elitewebsites.co.za">This website was designed by <span>www.elitewebsites.co.za</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem through the code you've provided, so there's probably a conflict with some other element in your website.

Comment: Like I've said the problem only seems to happen when the website is hosted online, any test carried out offline does not lead to the issue, it only appears when accessing the website online and not in offline debugging.

Comment: Then, it's impossible for us to reproduce your problem unless you share your website url. ;)

Comment: www.elitewebsites.co.za/Index.html

Comment: I have still been unable to reproduce your problem in the live version of your site. Which browser throws the issue you've mentioned?

Comment: Hey thanks for still trying, so far only Samsung Internet browser causes the problem, there's no black boxes in chrome... I've tried changing all my Spans to Divs and using flexboxes where i can but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 100%;
}
```

Add this to HTML tag also